# Get data from Siebel to VB6 project

Tags: vb.net, vb6, siebel

I am doing migration project (Console Application) from VB6 to VB.Net which gets the data from Siebel and process it. Our development systems doesn't have Siebel installed because it is a costly software. I would like to know is there any other way that I can get the Siebel data in my application code with out installing the full Siebel software?

I saw an another software (**Siebel Sync Client (Janus)**) which is free. If I install this software will it be resolving this issue?

My code is

Siebel Login

```
Public goSiebelApplication As SiebelDataControl
Set goSiebelApplication = CreateObject("SiebelDataControl.SiebelDataControl.1")
goSiebelApplication.Login siebelConnectString, userId, password
```

I am getting below error when CreateObject line is getting executed

[image]

Data Access code is

```
Dim oBoActivity As SiebelBusObject
Dim oBcActivity As SiebelBusComp
Dim oBoDocCategory As SiebelBusObject
Dim oBcDocCategory As SiebelBusComp
Dim oBcPolicy As SiebelBusComp

Set oBoActivity = goSiebelApplication.GetBusObject("Action")
Set oBcActivity = oBoActivity.GetBusComp("Action")
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need Siebel installed. As Siebel has COM interface, and it is possible to use that in .Net (for example with C#) you should add the DLL files to the project:

- Interop.SiebelApplicationServer.dll
- Interop.SiebelBusObjectInterfaces.dll
- Interop.TWSiebelLib.dll

Most probably same thing was used in your old VB project - so just look for the dll files ;)